# I used lambda to list collection indexes from mongodb,but I take an error in eclipse

Tags: java, mongodb, lambda, java-8

```
MongoCollection cols = db.getCollection("test01");
cols.listIndexes().forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.toJson()));
```

I just want to implement the `Block` interface's method `apply(Document t)` by lambda,but I take an error at the seconde line:

```
The method forEach(Block) is ambiguous for the type ListIndexesIterable
```

And I have test the following code successfully,so my JDK version is OK:

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println(1111)).start();
```

my lambda grammar must wrong, can anybody help me. Thanks anyone help me.

Comment: even if you define the type in your Block function as such `.forEach((Document t) -> System.out.println(t.toJson());` ?

Comment: yes,and I got another error:

Comment: It might help to share this error with us...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grammar is fine, but it looks like [`ListIndexesIterable`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/ListIndexesIterable.html) has 2 `forEach` methods. 1 from `Iterable` which takes a `Consumer` and 1 from `MongoIterable` which takes a `Block`, and your lambda can be used to instantiate either.

The solution is to "tag" the lambda with the wanted type:

```
cols.listIndexes().forEach((Block<...>) t -> System.out.println(t.toJson()));
```

Answer (score 3):

`MongoIterable` implements `Iterable` interface which also has default method `forEach(Consumer)`. So your `Block` conflicts with `Consumer`. Add an explicit cast to Block to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Because ambiguous method call, both
**forEach(Block)** in **MongoIterable** and **forEach(Consumer)** in **Iterable** match.

I used mongo-drive 3.4.1 to test your program just now, and change your code to be below then run normally.

```
cols.listIndexes().forEach((Block<? super Document>) t -> System.out.println(t.toJson()));
```